# Creating HTML according to files existence in the file system

Tags: html, xml

I am writing a web application (I am a newbie), where the markup is created by XSL and XML transformations and the style is declared by css files and also some use of JavaScript. I need to create a web page that part of its content is the information on files in a specific directory in the file system.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about the client's file system, or the server's?

If the client's, what you are asking is basically impossible for security reasons without some specific browser plugins/extensions (like a java applet with the right access) - you probably don't want to get into that.

If you are talking about the server file system, you will need some sort of server side language to read the file(s) and return them to browser requests. The sort of things that do that are PHP, ASP.NET, Ruby on Rails, etc...also look into Server Side Includes - that may be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: I am using a servlet, that among other do the XML XSL transformation. can I use it to help create the page. I can create an xml doc that describe the file system structure and transform it but I would like to see if there is a better, more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the client's filesystem or the server's filesystem? If it's the client's, these tools are inadequate (as access to the client's OS is severely restricted for security purposes). I think most people go with a Java applet for stuff like that.

Comment: I mean the server file system